# How to add 1 on the "like" value using QueryDSL

Tags: java, postgresql, querydsl

In my postgres db, I have a cell to save how many people clicked "i like" for the corresponding post. However, I am wondering if my current solution is concurrent in postgres. What I did now is two steps in my dao class.

1) fetch the current value in DB. 
2) add 1 and then update it.

If no, how can I make it concurrent? I am using Java (querydsl) and Postgres. Can any one help, please?

Update:

Thanks for the answers. One thing I didn't make clear is that I use querydsl. So I don't use normal column way. But still thanks.

Comment: Something like `UPDATE YOUR_TABLE SET VALUE = VALUE + 1` directly in the database.

Comment: Note : you might need to know who "liked" (and prevent from liking multiple times). So another solution would be to store all the likes (maybe in a non-relational database). When a user likes, you insert a "like" in your "likes" table. When you need to know the "like count", just perform a sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your table is named `posts` and you have a `QPosts` query class, then you can do:

```
QPosts p = QPosts.posts;
queryFactory.
   update(q).
   set(q.likes, q.likes.add(1)). 
   where(q.id.eq(42));
```

This would then generate the following SQL:

```
update posts
  set likes = likes + 1
where posts.id = 42
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is this querydsl sql an atomic operation? Or do I need to make the method synchronized?

Comment: Well the `UPDATE` is atomic so you don't need to bother with synchronizing the Java method.

Answer (score 1):

I've never do PostgreSQL but I found something.

```
UPDATE tableName 
SET likes = likes + 1;
```

Tell me if it's good,

Happy if I help you !